# Comparing the permutations of two strings in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I've just started out with learning C-basics and tried solving this problem where, we have to check if two strings are equal provided any permutation.
You may refer to this link: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/two-strings-4/

I just wanted to get some solutions on how can I improve my code which gives the output as only 'NO':

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, m, n, o, p;
    char a[100000], b[100000], *c, *d;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        scanf("%s %s", a, b);
    }
    for (k = 0; a[k] != '\0'; k++)
    {
        n = rand() % k;
    }
    for (m = 0; b[m] != '\0'; m++)
    {
        o = rand() % m;
    }
    for (p = 0; p < j; p++)
    {
        if (a[n] == b[o])
        {
            printf("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NO");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So Permutations of string `s1` should be equal to string `s2` which means all characters all character in string `s1` should be present in `s2` and count of each of those characters in both the strings should be same - what the problem in executing that? You might want to use an integer array of size `26` for that.

Comment: You reserving 200k bytes with your arrays :/ That's ridiculous (and easy to exploit). Better us a length specifier in your scanf format.

Comment: As Observer said you can just count the occurrence times of each character and compare these counts if it is possible or not. And welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only want some suggestions about the improving your code.

1. You may use `scanf("%20s", str1)` or something like that to improve the memory footprint of your answer. You will need to use a loop to read the strings. `%20s` asks scanf to read 20 characters at most. You can tailor the number according to your needs.
2. You can get the length of the string via `strlen` function included from `string.h`.
3. You just want to check the occurrence times of each character. In your case you can use an integer array of length 26, or two depending on your algorithm.
4. Use better variable names. This really helps if you do something wrong in algorithm.

[This would be my solution just for one string comparision](https://repl.it/repls/AwfulLostCylinders)

### Detailed Evaluation of User Code

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    scanf("%s %s", a, b);
}
```

This code block reads all lines. C is evaluated sequentially, so instead you will need to do this like

```
for (j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
{
    scanf("%s %s", a, b);
    /* do comparision for each here */
}
```

As I mentioned above C is evaluated sequentially, so the next 2 for loops also evaluates and results in a randomly selected 2 characters from both strings. I did not analyzed the probability, but from my senses I can say it won't hit same character most of the time. It is better to loop over a string, than pray for RNG to hit.

```
for (k = 0; a[k] != '\0'; k++)
{
    n = rand() % k;
}
for (m = 0; b[m] != '\0'; m++)
{
    o = rand() % m;
}
```

The above code will execute and only produces 1 output for each for loop and due to randomness of it I cannot tell which outcome it will lead.

```
for (p = 0; p < j; p++)
{
    if (a[n] == b[o])
    {
    printf("YES");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO");
    }
}
```

This for loop will execute exactly `i` times as the current value of `j` will be `i` as the first for loop executed before. Each of these loops will compare the same `a[n]` and `b[o]` from the reasons explained above. so the outcome will be `YES`x`i` or `NO`x`i`. No matter what the strings are.

Hope this explains what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I think the user who asked the question is actually having an issue where the only thing that is output is "NO".

Comment: I truly agree with Yakup Turkan for solving the problem and it worked, thanks a lot!! But, I also wish to know where am I wrong or say, why can't I get the answer in the way I tried? Sorry if this seems nuisance but, since am just a beginner, I'm curious to know what's the problem with my code as OrdoFlammae commented.

Comment: @SujayRittikar you should try to explain what segments of your code are doing - and what is their intended purpose & then only we can help.

Comment: @SujayRittikar I do not understand what you were trying with those for loops with rand functions. If you can explain what you think it does, I may say if it works as you expect or not and evaluate where the fault is.

Comment: @YakupTürkan I actually intended to get a random integer of the total no. of characters in the string. And, by continuing to loop those randomly taken integers, I could just compare the characters of both strings.

Comment: Each for evaluates within itself. so when you go out of the first for loop, you hit the end of the string. You are expecting to each hit the same character where its probability is low. Also I just noticed that you just compare the last strings, others are discarded before evaluation. I will try to come up with a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed Explanation! I could make out what was wrong clearly.

Comment: @SujayRittikar also a funfact, because you did not set the random number seed via `srand` you will get same result each time. to set the random to be random you can use `srand(time())` and you need to include `time.h`

Comment: Ohh! So, basically    rand() doesn't change the integer it picks every time it runs, it's kind of the same random integer from a set/array of integers. I'll try out    srand

Comment: @SujayRittikar no it changes, but in order to get different starting condition each time you need to set the seed to different number with `srand` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand

Comment: @YakupTürkan Got it

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve from the `rand()` function but certainly you need now to find different permutations to do that.  Permutations of string s1 should be equal to string s2 which means  all character in string s1 should be present in s2 and count of each of those characters in both the strings should be same

Here is a working version:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 //CHECKING IF STRING TWO IS ANY PERMUTATION OF STRING ONE

 int main()
 {
     char str_one[]="abbcd";
     char str_two[]="bcab";
     int  arr[26]={0};
     int index=0;
     int len_one=strlen(str_one);
     int len_two=strlen(str_two);
     int val;

     if(len_one!=len_two)
     {
          printf("NO");
          exit(0);
     }

     while(index<len_one)
     {
         ++arr[str_one[index++]-'a'];
     }
     index=0;
     while(index<len_two)
     {
         --arr[str_two[index++]-'a'];
         if(arr[str_two[index]-'a']<0)
         {
             printf("NO");
             exit(0);
         }
     }
     index=0;

     while(index<26)
     {
         if(arr[index]!=0)
         {
           printf("NO");
           exit(0);
         }
         ++index;
     }

     printf("yes");

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For compare two string use of `strcmp()` :

```
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

Parameters :

1. str1 − This is the first string to be compared.
2. str2 − This is the second string to be compared.

Return Value :

This function return values that are as follows :

- if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
- if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
- if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   char str1[15];
   char str2[15];
   int ret;


   strcpy(str1, "abcdef");
   strcpy(str2, "ABCDEF");

   ret = strcmp(str1, str2);

   if(ret < 0) {
      printf("str1 is less than str2");
   } else if(ret > 0) {
      printf("str2 is less than str1");
   } else {
      printf("str1 is equal to str2");
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Question is more than just comparing the strings using `strcmp`.

Comment: I tried to compare the strings with the strcmp before. But, that just got me an SIGSEGV/Segmentation error.